# In Windows system ssh-key

Tags: addition, ssh-keys

When I am adding ssh key by Gitbash so i am getting this error:
Enter PIN for authenticator:
Provider "internal" returned failure -4
Unable to load resident keys: device not found
So Please anyone help me.  I get stuck in this.
in one of the solution it is given for Mac not for windows.

I am trying to add but it is not adding anyway

Answer (score -1):

I did this and it worked went to the .ssh folder and there is a text file that you need to copy and paste it in GITHUB

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).